# Add an alias for a property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, properties

I think this is fairly simple,

Is there a simple way to add a secondary name for a property (I think this one is String specific – I'm not sure), i.e.,

```
c = length // this line pseudo code

'hello world'.length // returns 11
'hello world'.c      // this line is pseudo code, meant to return 11
```

In the example above, there's an alias created for the property length. Is that possible to do in JavaScript?

Comment: What are you trying to solve? Because it sounds a bit like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "c", {get: function() { return this.length }})` https://jsfiddle.net/7krcvhne/

Comment: This answered my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically access object property using variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4244896/dynamically-access-object-property-using-variable)

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**1. With Bracket Notation**

With [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation), you can access the property like so:

```
'hello world'[c]
```

This does the same thing as `'hello world'.length` if `c` is `'length'` as a string.

```js
var c = 'length';
console.log('hello world'[c]);
```

The only difference is that the property is a string. Bracket notation is a property accessor.

**2. With `Object.defineProperty()`**

Now if you want an alias:

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'c', {
    get: function() {
        return this.length;
    }
});

console.log("hello world".c);
```

The above uses  [`Object.defineProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) to define a property for the existing object, String's `prototype` object. That way, all instances of a string will have this new property. Per the documentation:

> The `Object.defineProperty()` method defines a new property directly on an object, or modifies an existing property on an object, and returns the object.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, descriptor)`

Where `obj` is the object being modified, `prop` is the new or existing property, and `descriptor` is the descriptor for the new or existing property.

Thus, the above defines a property for the object `String.prototype`, with name `c`. Its descriptor is a get function which returns the length of `this`. In the example above, `this` refers to the string so it returns the length of the string. You can read more about getters [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

---

This can also be defined for more types by changing to the applicable prototype (`obj`), such as using `Object.prototype` instead. However, this has potential issues, as trying to return `this.length` on an object *without* a length property will return undefined, as seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/v0Lv1org/1/). You can also use [`Object.defineProperties`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) to define multiple properties at a time.

Comment: Can you use a lazy getter, since strings are immutable?

Answer (score 10):

To expand on @AndrewLi's answer, there are a bunch of alias-like things you can do with `Object.defineProperty()`.

- **Read-only** alias *(same as his answer)*
- **Synced** alias modifies source when it's modified
- **Defaulted** alias reads from or "defaults to" source until changed (at which point relationship is broken)

I'll write them as functions that relate a **source** object with property, **sProp**, and a **target** object with property, **tProp**. Source and target *can* be the same object (allowing a property to be an alias to another property on the same object), but this is not a requirement. Also, the source (or target) can be a prototype (like Object.prototype, String.prototype, etc..)

### "Normal" assignment

This one's not really an alias, nor does it use `Object.defineProperty()`. The target is assigned the **VALUE** of the source, not a reference to it. This means that when the source changes, the target does not.

```js
function assign(target, tProp, source, sProp) {
  target[tProp] = source[sProp];
  return target;
}

let myTarget = {}
let mySource = {b: 12}

myTarget = assign(myTarget, 'a', mySource, 'b')

// "alias" was assigned source value
console.log('"alias":',myTarget.a) // 12

// changes to source independent of "alias"
mySource.b = 13
console.log("source:", mySource.b) // 13
console.log('"alias":', myTarget.a) // still 12
```

### Read-only Alias (the above solution)

When the property definition does not have a setter is it effectively a read-only value. Changes to the source property will be reflected in the alias; however, you cannot set the value of the alias.

```js
function read(target, tProp, source, sProp){
  Object.defineProperty(target, tProp, {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get(){
      return source[sProp];
    }
  })
  return target;
}

let myTarget = {}
let mySource = {b: 12}

myTarget = read(myTarget, 'a', mySource, 'b')

// Alias gets value from source
console.log("alias:", myTarget.a) // 12

// No setter effectively means read-only
myTarget.a = 15
console.log("alias:", myTarget.a) // 12

// Changes to source are seen in target
mySource.b = 15
console.log("source:", mySource.b) //15
console.log("target:", myTarget.a) //15
```

### Synced Alias

This alias modifies the read-only version above to set the source property whenever the alias (target) property is set. In this way the source and target always remain in sync.

```js
function sync(target, tProp, source, sProp){
  Object.defineProperty(target, tProp, {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get(){
      return source[sProp];
    },
    set(value){
      source[sProp] = value;
    }
  })
  return target;
}

let myTarget = {}
let mySource = {b: 12}

myTarget = sync(myTarget, 'a', mySource, 'b')

// Alias gets value from source
console.log("alias:", myTarget.a) // 12

// Changing alias' value modifies the source
myTarget.a = 15
console.log("alias:", myTarget.a) // 15
console.log("source:", mySource.b) // 15

// Changing source modifies alias still
mySource.b = 20
console.log("source:", mySource.b) // 20
console.log("alias:", myTarget.a) // 20
```

### Alias as Default

This allows you to default an alias/target value until otherwise updated. Unlike the read-only case, you can change the alias/target value, yet unlike the the sync, when you change the alias you do not update the source - instead the alias becomes a regular value.

```js
function setDefault(target, tProp, source, sProp){
  Object.defineProperty(target, tProp, {
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true,
    get(){
      return source[sProp];
    },
    set(value){
      delete target[tProp];
      target[tProp] = value;
    }
  })
  return target;
}

let myTarget = {}
let mySource = {b: 12}

myTarget = setDefault(myTarget, 'a', mySource, 'b')

// Alias gets value from source
console.log('alias:', myTarget.a) // 12

// Changing source modifies alias still
mySource.b = 15
console.log('source:', mySource.b) // 15
console.log('alias:', myTarget.a) // 15

// Changing alias' value DOES NOT modify source
myTarget.a = 20
console.log("alias:", myTarget.a) // 20
console.log("source:", mySource.b) // 15

// The relationship between source and alias is BROKEN
mySource.b = 100
console.log("source:", mySource.b) // 100
console.log("alias:", myTarget.a) // 20
```