# JavaScript - prototype as a self invoking function (IIFE)

Tags: javascript

I would like to define a prototype on String that is a self-invoking function

```
String.prototype.overEstimatedLength = (function() {
   return this.length + 12345
})()
```

and then use it like this

```
'hello world'.overEstimatedLength
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. **Is something like that syntactically possible and why** is the example above not working?

**Note: I know that property definition would be more appropriate (such as a Getter), I'm specifically interested in self-invoking functions.**

Comment: What is the purpose of creating an alias for `.length`? Note, `this` with IIFE is not `String`

Comment: is this kind of homework? There was already a suspiciously similar question from half an hour ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39431230/add-an-alias-for-a-property-in-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript getters and setters for dummies?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/812961/javascript-getters-and-setters-for-dummies)

Comment: that's why I'm asking, because I answered on the question you mentioned, but I realised my answer wasn't correct. @Siguza you read my note I hope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your example is that there isn't actually such a thing as a "self-invoking function", only an "*immediately*-invoked function expression", with the emphasis on *immediately*.

Consider something like this:

```
String.prototype.foo = alert('foo');
'foo'.foo;
'foo'.foo;
```

This runs `alert('foo')` *immediately*, then stores the result in `String.prototype.foo` . . . and then just retrieves that result a few times (doing nothing with it). So `'foo'` will get alerted only once.

Your example is similar; you are *immediately* invoking your function expression.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to define a getter on `String.prototype`

```js
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'overEstimatedLength', {
  get: function() {
    return this.length + 12345;
  }
});
console.log('hello'.overEstimatedLength)
```

Your code doesn't work because it's executing your function immediately and assigning the result of that to `String.prototype.overEstimatedLength`. That is, it's almost exactly the same as...

```
function myFunc() {
    return this.length + 12345
}
String.prototype.overEstimatedLength = myFunc();
```

The following would kind of work, but you'd call it as a function, notice that you are returning a function, so that gets assigned to `String.prototype`

```js
String.prototype.overEstimatedLength = (function() {
   return function() {
     return this.length + 12345;
   }
})()

console.log('something'.overEstimatedLength())
```